# SAN Admin vs. DB Admin free allocated tempdb

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I really want to understand. My SAN-Admin told me I have to make sure my TempDB does not grow to max hard disk space.
I have 380 Gig on a dedicated disk, on a dedicated LUN, on a dedicated machine.
My SAN-Admin has a colorful fancy reporting in place, informing him every hour when ever a disk is 80% full. He treats it as crytical and he forwards it to management.

I'm stuck like Don Quijote explaining to everybody, why I don't give a rats a*s about the tempdb disk size. What I want to see instead is the allocated and free space for tempdb. And I'm telling them MS SQL won't free the allocated space on it self because it says, when the space is allocated now it is most likely it will be allocated the next time, again. So why bother allocating it again and again?

I know the SAN Admin treats every server the same, every disk the same. He has got a server farm to manage. There is no difference in DB or simple Web Server out of his perspective.

Now I need you. Is there any perfectly good reason why a any reporting should treat every server, even every DB Server equally, except for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: For them its all same onus lies on you to explain the management about the tempdb file usage, why it does not gives space back after task it done, and also why it would be bad idea to shrink it. What SAN admin is doing is by fancy report he is putting ball in your court, just in case if tempdb full causes server to become unresponsive he has perfect alibi to say that its was DBA who did not took care of it. You have to give counter advise about possible slowness and performance issue if you keep shrinking tempdb file. Instead forecast the space requirement and give it to management

Comment: "I have 380 Gig on a dedicated disk" Only one? Sounds like your admin has a simplified view of the world. Temp db will shrink and grow of its own accord depending upon the demands place upon it. If it bothers him so much then ask for separate and dedicated volume for temp db. Make sure its bigger than you could possibly grow it to now. Then  set your tempdb =79% of the available space. In theory it should never trigger his report.

Comment: No chance for more hardware. At least not whilst it's not for free. I got to pull this stunt on a management level. So I'm hoping for MS blogs, whitepapers, recommendations, anything simple enough for management to understand why I'm now willing to castrate my server. If you guys got nothing, I'll have to draw pictures my self ;)

Comment: Doing the cost (invest+maintenance) calculation of the 20% of purchased storage no-one can use can be enlightening for management. It's a good thing to have margins, and default monitoring policies, but blindly applying them everywhere is a waste of money.

Comment: If the SAN Admin is going to insist that you not use more than 80% of the available space and you are going into that, then you need more space.  Yes, you are technically correct, but there is a way forward without causing a rift between you and the SAN Admin.  Just request more space for the volume.  If he won't give you any additional space, then elevate that refusal to management.